# ngForOf and ngIf with Iteration condition

Tags: angular

I have the following markup

```
<template ngFor let-childTag [ngForOf]="marketsTag?.children" let-i="index">
<div
   *ngIf="indexStartDropDownMore >= i"  class="markets-filter__tab"
  [ngClass]="{ 'markets-filter__tab--active': i === selectedTab }"
  (click)="menuToggle(i, childTag.marketTagId)"
  (appMoreDropdown)="childTagLogic($event, i, marketsTag?.children.length)">
  {{ childTag?.name }}
</div>
</template>
```

value `indexStartDropDownMore` сhanges dynamically during each iteration (event OnInit) via event `appMoreDropdown` (fires on OnInit of iteration element) in method `childTagLogic`. The condition `*ngif` does not work but `[hidden]="indexStartDropDownMore <= i"` working well.

Any ideas?

Comment: it doesn't make sense - you use same condition for `*ngIf` and `[hidden]` and get different results? Both of these accepts booleans - so how one can act differently? And could you explain this `[ngForOf]="marketsTag?.children"` - what kind of structure are you iterating through?

Comment: Boolean condition does not work with *ngIf -it not show content always. 
 'marketsTag?.children' is array.If i delete ngif and show condition some like that {{indexStartDropDownMore > i}}-somewhere show true ,somewhere show false(to end) for the each iteration.It should be taken into account that the value indexStartDropDownMor changes during the iteration

Comment: if i try something like that  *ngIf="5< i"  all work fine

Comment: Ok, so its clear that problem is in `indexStartDropDownMore`. You can try to see what values it gets, like creating a fn in class `log(val){console.log(val)}` and display those values `{{log(indexStartDropDownMore)}}`

Comment: I saw the following order 'underfined',number '13' 12 times,then console show number '11' 13 times,once again number '11' 13 times. The sequence itself consists of 13 elements

Comment: You can use `<ng-container` instead of `<template`, then you can use the more common binding syntax with the same result `<ng-container *ngFor"let childTag] of marketsTag?.children; let-i=index">`